# How To scroll down the one of the section in page using selenuim webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In My Web site has one section where we can scroll the particular section of the page. I know hot to scroll down the page. But i can not scroll down the page the particular section 
Please check the screen show

Club profile page is not updating on Registration page and Group after editing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaScriptExecutor`

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

This will scroll to the id you want to.